# Java Spring MVC Get Max Entry from MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, model-view-controller

I cannot figure out how to get the maximum value for a specific field in my mongo collection. I have tried the following which I found online and which works in the command line for mongo but does not work in Java. Can someone please, please help me figure what I need to do in order to use this in Java with the Spring framework?

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Can you include, your java code which you are trying? Are you using spring-data?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.collection.find({},{field_name:1,_id:0}).sort({field_name:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, nothing there needs to be in quotes? This isn't working for me :( So I have entered it like this (collection was previously defined):                                     Document doc = collection.find({},{field_name:1,_id:0}).sort({field_name:-1}).limit(1);